# Can a Google Chrome Extension popup window remain open as a new window is opened on top of it and then closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome Extension that uses the `Background.html` and `background.js` files to show this popup window when the chrome extension icon in the tray menu is clicked on....

[image]

---

Inside my popup is a button to generate a screenshot image of the current tab URL and it then uploads the image to my server and fills in the text input with the URL of my image upload.

I am now wanting to add the capability to select a region on the webpage screen and generate a screenshot image cropped to be just the content inside the selected region like this image below shows the region selected on the page....

[image]

---

My roblem now is that I cannot simply have a button in my popup take me into region selection mode on the page.  I could but it would close the popup window and I have researched and found out that you cannot programtically open the popup.

So once the popup would close, I would no longer be able to edit the record loaded in it before.

I am trying to come up with a new solution to achieve my desired result.

---

**Idea 1**

Move all the functionality that my current background popup has into a modal window displayed on the actual webpage.

This would be a big change as it would require a lot of message passing as the modal code would not have access to theextension API which is used to generate the screenshot and get all the tabs data.

I could then open a modal that looks like my popup in the image above when the extension icon is clicked on.

When the generate screenshot button is clicked it would then send a message to the background script to get the tab API and generate the screenshot and then send it back as a message to the content script in the page.

As for my new feature of selecting a region and creating image of that region.  The modal would have a button to do that and on click would hide the modal window.  Next it would let me make the selection  which on edn would send a message to background again and generate a screenshot and crop it to the coordinates of my selection and return it back in a return message to the content script which would then show the hidden modal window and update the image inside to show the new image.

This is the hardest way bu the best I think.

---

**Idea 2)**

If it is possibble even, on a button click inside my current popup would then launch a new popup window of the current page and allow me to make my selection region and generate the image which on completion would close the popup window and send the result back to my extension popup.

I do not know if this would work because I am unsure if the extension popup would auto-close when I click the new popup window?

---

Does anyone know of other way to accomplish this or if my ideas would be practical?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Adblock Plus](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome) for inspiration.

They have a popup with "Block Element" button that switches to "now interact with the page" mode.

After the user clicks, they open follow-up UI injected into the page.

---

In any case, clicking outside the popup will make it lose focus, which closes it by design.

You could instruct the user to click your button again after they interact with the page, or you would need to inject some UI into the page itself.

Comment: Thanks I will look at that extension.  I think If I switch to a Modal window I can keep the same look and feel that I have now and using the method in adblock I should be able to do this thanks for sharing thew info it is a rare situation!